# Create a DSN for the function odbc_connect for Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, odbc

The information I have concerning the Oracle database O need to connect to using PHP through EasyPHP is the following: user, password, host, port, service. I'm new to ODBC. I tried to use the function odbc_connect, but I keep getting errors simply because I don't know how to make a DSN.

I tried using this:

```
$dns_db="DRIVER={DataDirect 32-BIT SequeLink 5.4};HOST=localhost; PORT=2399;ServerDataSource=maDB;"
```

But I don't know what `{DataDirect 32-BIT SequeLink 5.4}` means, and it seems like I need to know the database name so I can put it in the ServerDataSource.

How do I make this DSN thing?

Comment: The exact nature of the DSN is going to vary from system to system, driver to driver, case by case.  Please ask your Oracle DBA for assistance constructing it properly.  If you don't *have* a DBA... well ... may whatever gods you believe in have mercy upon your soul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the driver name as it shows up in the ODBC manager. In my computer I have `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` and `Oracle in instantclient_11_2` to choose from:

[image]

Try to use a driver provided by Oracle; the Microsoft one lacks many basic features.

But I'd recommend you to create a system ODBC so you can assign a name of your choice and simply refer to it by such name. Additionally, that allows to configure additional options with the driver's GUI:

[image]

Last but not least, my final advice is to dump ODBC completely and use the OCI extension. Coding a PHP app with ODBC is frustrating.